# Handle error for duplicate entries - PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, try-catch

What is the proper way to handle error on duplicate entries for PHP/MySQL?

The code below is not working even tho the code 1062 is the right code for duplicate entries. Should i use DBO instead here? Unfortunately i'm not familiar yet.

```php
<?php 
try {
    mysql_query('INSERT INTO TP2_ORGANISME VALUES (A0A0, Equiterre, 1, 
                        /photos/equiterre_logo.png, Steve Guilbault, steve@equiterre.org');
} catch {
    if (mysql_errno() == 1062) 
      echo 'Duplicate key entry';
} 
?>
```

I'm just looking for a simple try catch or anything that can just let me print a message to the user who entered a duplicate that he has to enter another value for the primary key.

thanks

Comment: **WARNING**: Do not use the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface which was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Here parameters are **NOT** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and this has severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) in this code. Escape **any** and all user data, especially from `$_POST` or `$_GET`.

Comment: This code can't possibly work. I'm not sure where you found it, but I'm expecting the resource you're using to learn how to use MySQL in PHP is way too old to be trusted. `mysql_query` is no longer available, and besides, you can't insert data like that. You'll need to work through a basic SQL primer before any of this is going to make much sense, or use a database abstraction layer like e [RedBeanPHP](https://redbeanphp.com/), [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent) for a softer start.

Answer (score 7):

`mysql_query()` does not throw exceptions (and only exceptions can be caught). `mysqli_` and PDO can, if you enable it to. `mysql_` is also very obsolete (and has been for many years already), so use PDO or MySQLi with exception-mode enabled, and it'll work. Both these APIs support prepared statements, so you should use that too if you start inputting variables in your query.

For MySQLi, you need `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` before the connection, and for PDO you need `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

MySQLi example

```php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $databasename);
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

try {
    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO TP2_ORGANISME 
                               VALUES ('A0A0', 'Equiterre', 1, '/photos/equiterre_logo.png', 'Steve Guilbault', 'steve@equiterre.org')");
} catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
    if ($e->getCode() == 1062) {
        // Duplicate user
    } else {
        throw $e;// in case it's any other error
    }

}
```

PDO example

```php
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$databasename;charset=utf8", $username, $password);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // Enables exception mode

try {
    $pdo->query("INSERT INTO TP2_ORGANISME 
                               VALUES ('A0A0', 'Equiterre', 1, '/photos/equiterre_logo.png', 'Steve Guilbault', 'steve@equiterre.org')");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    if ($e->getCode() == 1062) {
        // Duplicate user
    } else {
        throw $e;// in case it's any other error
    }
}
```

- [MySQLi exception class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-sql-exception.php) and [`mysqli_report()`](https://www.php.net/mysqli_report)
- [PDO exception class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php) and [`PDO::setAttribute()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php)

When you start introducing variables into your queries, look into using a prepared statement ([How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)).

Comment: Thanks, but i'm not sure what to do this with line :  $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$databasename;charset=utf8", $username, $password); - Where can i find the hostname and/or database name, honestly im using a VM and i'm kind of confused right now.

Comment: That creates the connection, similar to how you have `mysql_connect()` today. You should remove all instances using the `mysql_` functions, and use PDO or MySQLi instead.

Comment: On a VM you'll often start with `localhost` and `root`, but you'll want to lock that down and **be absolutely certain that remote users can't connect**, especially if your root account has no password.

Comment: okay, do i need to get the mysql extension ? It says Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_report()

Comment: Yes, you need the mysql and mysqli/PDO extensions.

Answer (score -2):

I found this block of code really helped capture the 1062 error, and then redirect from the signup page to the login page, if the error happened. Tested it, and it all works.

```
catch (PDOException $e) {

  if(str_contains($e, '1062 Duplicate entry')) {
      header("Location: login.php");

  }
      die("Error inserting user details into database: " .  $e->getMessage());

}
```